# Why my answer was deleted even if it was helpful?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Moderator [deleted my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24294961/1466198). The questioner was happy enough that his problem gone away afterwards. And that's why the moderator deleted my post. Maybe somebody can tell me how to contact him? What was wrong?

Comment: Moderators seldom seek out content to delete. They have too much to do. More than likely there were _several_ flags from other members of the community calling out your post as a non-answer. The Moderator, in that case, simply agreed.

Comment: It is worth noting, however, that **Stack Overflow does not accept skype/e-mail conversations**. We expect all content pertaining to questions and answers to be posted publicly on the site, where everyone can benefit. If you want to have a private conversation, do so. Don't use Stack Overflow to do it.

Comment: Also, I don't see anything wrong with calling out a moderator by name for their actions. There's a reason that this information is given publicly. Mods are just like anyone else, to be held accountable for their actions on the site. So I don't think *that* is rude or improper. But you should still do so *respectfully*, which judging from your now-deleted answer below, you might want to work on...

Comment: How a user asking why their answer was deleted is redirected towards guidance on how to use a flag?

Comment: @Braiam Because if they understood when the flag is meant to be used they'd understand why their answer was deleted

Comment: @Nick which is backwards. They should not have to do such mental gymnastics. The NAA flag is only one of the mechanism why we delete answers. 20k users can delete answers for any reason. How about if it was deleted because it was spam? Or rude? Or any other reason not used for NAA?

Comment: *"They should not have to do such mental gymnastics."* - There's no mental gymnastics here, it's pretty clear. *"How about if it was deleted because it was spam? Or rude? Or any other reason not used for NAA?"* - But it wasn't so that's irrelevant. A better question, why add an answer to a 6 year old question the OP of which hasn't been online (on meta) in 2 years when the actual answer to their question (why their answer in particular was deleted) has already been provided?

Comment: @Nick this question asks why. NAA is one possible answer, not the answer.

Comment: @Braiam It asks why _their_s was, not why in general, _their_s was because it was NAA

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is not an answer, it's a comment asking for more details so it was correctly deleted.

Answer should be just that: answer to the question, not asking for details/clarifications.

As for "how to contact" it's not relevant, you don't have to contact the specific moderator who deleted. If you wish to appeal the deletion you can flag your own answer, choose "Other" and explain why you want it undeleted.

Comment: (And the fact that asking the OP those questions led them to correctly fix their code doesn't mean it's an answer.)

Answer (score 14):

While you did end up helping the OP it was in the comments of your non-answer.

If you want your answer to be helpful you should edit it so that it contains the solution then flag it for moderator attention so it can be undeleted (if applicable).

Comment: Nice, was just going to add this into my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Common reasons [to delete an answer includes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers):

- commentary on the question or other answers
- asking another, different question
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- barely more than a link to an external site
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

In summary, **any post purported as answer which doesn't directly answers the question**. If you want to improve your answer, see the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) in the help page. Other answers already covered why your specific answer was deleted, which is included in the list.